# MVC 4 Dropdownlist Pass value by button?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have created a dropdownlist using html helper.
It's able to get the value and bind to dropdown.

How can i pass the selected dropdown value to controller?

My View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Language", new SelectList(ViewBag.LangList, "Text", "Value"))
<input type="button" class="btn" title="Filter By Language" 
    value="Filter By Language" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SURV_Answer_Result", "SURV_Answer", 
    new { Survey_ID = Model[0].Survey_ID, Language = ViewBag.LangList })'" />
```

My Controller to get Language and bind into dropdown:

```
public ActionResult SURV_GetLanguage(int Survey_ID)
{
  var getlanguagelist = from r in db.SURV_Question_Ext_Model
                        join s in db.SURV_Question_Model on r.Qext_Question_ID equals s.Question_ID
                        where s.Question_Survey_ID == Survey_ID
                        group new { r, s } by r.Qext_Language into grp
                        select grp.FirstOrDefault();

  foreach (var item in getlanguagelist.ToList())
  {
    List<SelectListItem> langResult = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var item2 in getlanguagelist)
    {
      SelectListItem temp = new SelectListItem();
      temp.Text = item2.r.Qext_Language;
      temp.Value = item2.r.Qext_Language;
      langResult.Add(temp);
    }
    ViewBag.LangList = langResult;
  }
  return View(ViewBag.Langlist) ;
}
```

And i want pass the Language to the controller below:

```
 public ActionResult SURV_Answer_Result(int Survey_ID, string Language)
 {
   List<AnswerQuestionViewModel> viewmodel = new List<AnswerQuestionViewModel>();
   SURV_GetLanguage(Survey_ID);
  // do whatever i want...
}
```

Comment: Firstly `ViewBag.LangList` is already `List<SelectListItem>` so `new SelectList(ViewBag.LangList, "Text", "Value")` is pointless extra overhead - just use `(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LangList`. You have given the the controls the name `Language` so your controller method needs a parameter `string Language`. But it would be far better to use a model and bind your dropdownlist to it.

Comment: Why are you handling button click in such an unusual way? What is the problem with a simple form submit?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i had to pass the language to another controller after get the language from dropdown list. Maybe you can provide some sample for my references? Thanks again.

Comment: OK, I see your problem - your not submitting a form - you just have a pointless `onclick` function which will redirect and pass nothing. Is the controller method you have shown a GET or POST method?

Comment: @StephenMuecke exactly, the controller method i shown is a GET method. Because i need to filter the question result based on language type. So i need to get the dropdownlist select value and pass to the controller.

Comment: @Edward.K, Answer added, but there is something strange about your controller code. Why do you generate a complex query `getlanguagelist`, then only use one property of it to generate the `List<SelectListItem>` which you assign to a `ViewBag` property. And then you just throw `getlanguagelist` away - all you do is `return View(ViewBag.Langlist);` which is pointless since its already in `ViewBag`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks and it works. I will try improve on my query. I still newbie on LINQ. Will take your advise seriously. Thanks again for your guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button in the view is`type="button"` and you have attached a `onclick` event which will just redirect to the `SURV_Answer_Result` passing the original `ViewBag` property back to the method (which will not bind to `string Language` because its `List<SelectListItem>`.

You need a form with `FormMethod.Get`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SURV_GetLanguage", "ControllerName", new { Survey_ID = Model[0].Survey_ID }, FormMethod.Get))
{
  @Html.DropDownList("Language", (Enumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LangList)
  <input type="submit" ... />
}
```

Notes:

1. The `Survey_ID` has been added to the form as a route value
2. `ViewBag.LangList` is `Enumerable<SelectListItem>` which is all that
   is required by the `DropDownList()` helper so there is no point in
   the extra overhead of creating another `SelectList` from it
   (`SelectList` IS `Enumerable<SelectListItem>`)

Comment: Thanks and it works. Appreciate your patience guidance.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have used would work if you change the method signature on the controller to `public ActionResult SURV_GetLanguage(int Survey_ID, string Language = null)`. You could then test for nulls and process as necessary.

However it would be better to wrap the dropdownlist inside a form, and use a POST request. Something like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SURV_GetLanguage","ControllerName",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("Language", new SelectList(ViewBag.LangList, "Text", "Value"))
    <input type="submit" class="btn" />
}
```

Then in the controller you could have a new method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SURV_GetLanguage(string Language)
{
     //Do whatever you want with language.
}
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I had edited my question. Thanks for your feedback. Will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways,

1) You can put your dropdown and submit button into a form containing action parameter. On button press, your form will be submitted to its action. Your action must contain a parameter with name 'Languages'. It will give you selected value.

All the parameters of action, if matching to 'name' property of controls, will contain their values on form submit.

2) You can get selected value from dropdown by using jquery and then use either window.location or build url for form's action and call submit.

Comment: Thanks for your useful advise!